# Creating a node programmatically for a user who doesn't have the permission to create nodes of that content type

Tags: nodes, users

Let's say user X does not have the permission to create nodes of the content type Y, but the user does something which triggers an action, and this action is supposed to create a node of type Y. Will this be possible?

I want to do this because I don't want the user to manually create content as he could mess things up; I'd rather have this automatically done, hence the user not having permissions to create this type of node.

I'm using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

If the code calls [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6) passing to the function a node object that is associated to user Y (i.e., the value of `node->uid` is the user ID of user Y), the function will save  the node without checking if a node of that content type can be created from the user. It is the code that calls `node_save()` that eventually checks if the user has the permission of creating that content type, or it's the code that shows the link to the form for creating a node of a content type that makes the link visible only to users who has the permission to create nodes of that content type.

`node_save()` allows you to save a node that is associated to a user who don't have the permission to create a node of the content type Y; the problem is eventually when the user X doesn't have the permission to update nodes of the content type Y, which would not allow the user to update the node that has been created for him.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're looking for a module, I know rules in D7 can absolutely do this. I believe rules in D6 can do this as well.